# Can I cast a map from <String, SObject> to <String, MyObject>?

Tags: apex

It seems like no.  I have a utility method

```
   public static Map<String, SObject> getMapOfStringToSObject(List<SObject> lstSObjs, String strKeyFieldName)
   {
       Map<String, SObject> mapStringToSObject = new Map<String, SObject>();
       for (SObject so : lstSObjs)
           mapStringToSObject.put((String)so.get(strKeyFieldName), so);

       return mapStringToSObject;
   }
```

But when I try to use it (with casting) I get System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String, SObject> to Map<String, MyObject> ()

Client code is

```
Map<String, MyObject> res = (Map<String, MyObject>)UtilsClass.getMapOfStringToSObject(someList, 'someStringField');
```

Sure I could not cast and loop over the results.  But the whole point of this is to abstract away the looping and not have to write it over and over.  I have similar methods (where I can cast successfully) that return a variety of types including among others

```
Map<String, List<SObject>>
Map<Id, List<SObject>>
```

Comment: Don't think you can do this. MyObject is not an sObject

Comment: is `MyObject` in your example code an apex class type?

Comment: This is a topic that has been touched on before I explain at a high level how up-casting and down-casting work https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/297775/54609. Furthermore I suggest you look at this post as well that goes into finer detail about problems with type casting in apex https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/125891/54609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this that's only slightly clunky.  If I tell my method the return type I want, I can instantiated it with newInstance()

```
public static Map<String, SObject> getMapOfStringToSObject(List<SObject> lstSObjs, String strKeyFieldName, Type mapType)
{
    Map<String, SObject> mapStringToSObject = (Map<String, SObject>) mapType.newInstance();
    for (SObject so : lstSObjs)
        mapStringToSObject.put((String)so.get(strKeyFieldName), so);

    return mapStringToSObject;
}
```

And client code:

```
Map<String, Account> res = (Map<String, Account>)UtilsCollection.getMapOfStringToSObject(accounts, 'Name', Map<String, Account>.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `MyObject` is an `SObject` (which it should be, given your code so far), the best I've been able to come up with is something like

`Map<String, MyObject> res = new Map<String, MyObject>(UtilsClass.getMapOfStringToSObject(someList, 'someStringField').values());`

Which makes use of the map constructor which takes a list.

Unfortunately, that forces you to use the record Id as the map key. In limited situations, you could use the field aliasing trick (in a query that uses `GROUP BY`) to make some other field be the "Id", but I have a feeling that's not going to work for your utility class.

I don't think it's practical to avoid a loop here.